# Infinispan issues porting a Camel application from standalone to camel-quarkus

Tags: apache-camel, quarkus, infinispan

I'm trying to port to camel-quarkus a standalone camel application that uses the Infinispan Component.
This is the route

```
package org.federico.swiftref.portfolio.route;

import org.apache.camel.BindToRegistry;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.component.infinispan.InfinispanConstants;
import org.apache.camel.component.infinispan.InfinispanOperation;
import org.apache.camel.converter.jaxb.JaxbDataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormat;
import org.apache.camel.support.builder.Namespaces;
import org.infinispan.client.hotrod.configuration.Configuration;
import org.infinispan.client.hotrod.configuration.ConfigurationBuilder;
//import org.federico.swiftref.portfolio.model.SepaplusSchemaImpl;

/**
 * A Camel Java DSL Router
 */
public class LoadIbanPlus extends RouteBuilder {

    @BindToRegistry("cacheContainerConfiguration")
    Configuration configuration;

    private static final String JAXB_CONTEXT_PATH = "org.federico.swiftref.sepaplus.ibanplus.jaxb";
    private static final String STAX_TOKENIZER_PATH = "//ibanplus_v3";

    public LoadIbanPlus() {
        configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .security()
                .authentication()
                .saslMechanism("DIGEST-MD5")
                .username("myuser")
                .password("myuser")
                .addServer()
                .host("localhost")
                .port(11222)
                .version(org.infinispan.client.hotrod.ProtocolVersion.PROTOCOL_VERSION_25)
                .addContextInitializer(new SepaplusSchemaImpl())
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * Let's configure the Camel routing rules using Java code...
     */
    public void configure() {

        DataFormat jaxb = new JaxbDataFormat(JAXB_CONTEXT_PATH);

        from("file:src/data/ibanplus?noop=true")
                .split().xtokenize(STAX_TOKENIZER_PATH, 'w', new Namespaces("", ""))
                .unmarshal(jaxb)
                .log("${body}")
                .to("dozer:mapIban?mappingFile=ibanMapping.xml&targetModel=org.federico.swiftref.portfolio.model.Iban")
                .setHeader(InfinispanConstants.OPERATION, constant(InfinispanOperation.PUT))
                .setHeader(InfinispanConstants.KEY, simple("${body.getRecordKey()}"))
                .setHeader(InfinispanConstants.VALUE, simple("${body}"))
                .log("${body.getInstitutionName()}")
                .to("infinispan:sepaplus-cache?cacheContainerConfiguration=#cacheContainerConfiguration");
    }

}
```

This is the pom.xml of standalone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.federico.swiftref</groupId>
  <artifactId>swiftref-files-portfolio</artifactId>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <name>A Camel Route</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <log4j2-version>2.13.3</log4j2-version>
  </properties>

  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <!-- Camel BOM -->
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-bom</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <scope>import</scope>
        <type>pom</type>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-main</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <version>${log4j2-version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- testing -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-infinispan</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-stax</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-jaxb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-dozer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-bean</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.infinispan.protostream</groupId>
      <artifactId>protostream-processor</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.federico.swiftref.sepaplus</groupId>
      <artifactId>ibanstructure-jaxb-classes</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.federico.swiftref.sepaplus</groupId>
      <artifactId>exclusionlist-jaxb-classes</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.federico.swiftref.sepaplus</groupId>
      <artifactId>ibanplus-jaxb-classes</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <!-- Allows the example to be run via 'mvn camel:run' -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <logClasspath>true</logClasspath>
          <mainClass>org.federico.swiftref.portfolio.MainApp</mainClass>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>

</project>
```

This is the pom of quarkus application

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.federico.swiftref</groupId>
  <artifactId>swiftref-files-portfolio-quarkus</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <properties>
    <compiler-plugin.version>3.8.1</compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven.compiler.parameters>true</maven.compiler.parameters>
    <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <quarkus-plugin.version>1.12.0.Final</quarkus-plugin.version>
    <quarkus.platform.artifact-id>quarkus-universe-bom</quarkus.platform.artifact-id>
    <quarkus.platform.group-id>io.quarkus</quarkus.platform.group-id>
    <quarkus.platform.version>1.12.0.Final</quarkus.platform.version>
    <surefire-plugin.version>3.0.0-M5</surefire-plugin.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>${quarkus.platform.group-id}</groupId>
        <artifactId>${quarkus.platform.artifact-id}</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.platform.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-core</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-main</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-file</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-jaxb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-stax</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-dozer</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-bean</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.camel.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>camel-quarkus-infinispan</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-resteasy</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-arc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-junit5</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
      <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.federico.swiftref.sepaplus</groupId>
      <artifactId>ibanstructure-jaxb-classes</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.federico.swiftref.sepaplus</groupId>
      <artifactId>exclusionlist-jaxb-classes</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.federico.swiftref.sepaplus</groupId>
      <artifactId>ibanplus-jaxb-classes</artifactId>
      <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus-plugin.version}</version>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
              <goal>generate-code</goal>
              <goal>generate-code-tests</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${compiler-plugin.version}</version>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <systemPropertyVariables>
            <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
            <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
          </systemPropertyVariables>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>native</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>native</name>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  <goal>verify</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <systemPropertyVariables>
                    <native.image.path>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}-runner</native.image.path>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    <maven.home>${maven.home}</maven.home>
                  </systemPropertyVariables>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
      <properties>
        <quarkus.package.type>native</quarkus.package.type>
      </properties>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

The application works fine when running standalone; when running inside quarkus the application doesn't connect to the server and gets this exception.

```
2021-02-27 10:48:57,472 ERROR [io.qua.run.Application] (Quarkus Main Thread) Failed to start application (with profile dev): org.infinispan.client.hotrod.exceptions.HotRodClientException:Request for messageId=5 returned server error (status=0x85): java.lang.SecurityException: ISPN006017: Unauthorized 'PUT' operation
        at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.protocol.Codec20.checkForErrorsInResponseStatus(Codec20.java:333)
        at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.protocol.Codec20.readHeader(Codec20.java:172)
        at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport.netty.HeaderDecoder.decode(HeaderDecoder.java:139)
        at org.infinispan.client.hotrod.impl.transport.netty.HintedReplayingDecoder.callDecode(HintedReplayingDecoder.java:94)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.handler.timeout.IdleStateHandler.channelRead(IdleStateHandler.java:286)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.AbstractEpollStreamChannel$EpollStreamUnsafe.epollInReady(AbstractEpollStreamChannel.java:792)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.processReady(EpollEventLoop.java:475)
        at io.netty.channel.epoll.EpollEventLoop.run(EpollEventLoop.java:378)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

2021-02-27 10:48:57,533 INFO  [io.quarkus] (Quarkus Main Thread) swiftref-files-portfolio-quarkus stopped in 0.060s
```

I realize that should be something different in the configuration since the excepion remains the same even though the server is down. The standalone application doesn't execute the route at all when the server is down or if I intentionally set wrong credentials. It stops right when executing the Constructor.

Any idea? Possibly the cacheContainerConfiguration must be build differently when running in the Quarkus ecosystem? Or any other library is missing?

For example I noticed that in quarkus the protostream-processor dependency must not be included in the pom, maybe it's already inside the camel-quarkus-infinispan stuff and it creates conflicts if included.
Cheers

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE
Eventually I figured out how to!
I have removed the ConfigurationBuilder from the route since Quarkus needs all those details in the application.properties file setting the following properties

```
quarkus.infinispan-client.server-list=localhost:11222
quarkus.infinispan-client.auth-username=myuser
quarkus.infinispan-client.auth-password=myuser
quarkus.infinispan-client.sasl-mechanism=DIGEST-MD5
quarkus.infinispan-client.use-auth=true
```

I have also changed the Infinispan endpoint URL that now is simpler. It contains just the name of the cache.

```
...
.to("infinispan:sepaplus-cache");
```

Thanks to Quarkus all the code is now definitely tidier